# Find the number of ascending integers which are less than $10^9$

Tags: combinatorics

> A positive integer $d$ is said to be ascending if in its decimal
>   representation $d = d_md_{m-1}\ldots d_2d_1$ we have $0<d_m\leq
>  d_{m-1}\le\cdots\leq d_2\leq d_1$. For example $112233$ or $6789$. Find the
>   number of such integers such that they are less than $10^9$.

First let me say for those who may be unaware that for a multiset $M = \{\infty x_1, \infty x_2\cdots \infty x_n\}$ there are $n+r-1\choose r$ multisubsets of $M$ which have $r$ elements.

I have a correct solution to this which is the following: Every such number will have atmost 9 digits and there are 9 available digits : $\{1,2,3,\ldots,9\}$. I think it is clear that for each multisubset of $M = \{\infty 1, \infty 2,\ldots ,\infty 9\}$ corresponds a unique ascending integer (all you do is arrange the elements of the multisubsets accordingly), so by the above formula there are $9$ ascending integers with 1 digit $10\choose 2$ ascending integers with 2 digits and so on to get a total of $\sum_{i=1}^9{9+i-1\choose i}$ ascending integers of smaller than $10^9$. However, in the back of the book it says there are ${18\choose 9}-1$ (which is equal to my result) such integers and I was curious how this number was derived, which is my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of having up to $9$ digits, lets impose the condition that each number have exactly $9$ digits, but we are allowed to have leading zeros. So, if you want to form an ascending integer with $k$ digits, you simply pick $9-k$ zeros and the same number of the other digits.

So, now we are looking for the number of multisubsets of the multiset $M' = \{\infty 0, \infty 1, \infty 2,\ldots ,\infty 9\}$ which have exactly $9$ elements. This is simply $\dbinom{10+9-1}{9} = \dbinom{18}{9}$. But this also counts picking $9$ zeros, i.e. the number $000000000$, which is not an ascending integer. Thus, the total number of ascending integers is $\dbinom{18}{9}-1$.